# How to change row and column names of a table in Matlab

Tags: matlab, user-interface

I have created a GUI in Matlab and this is how it looks:

[image]

I need to know if I can change the row and column names of the table during runtime and not some static name.

Is there any way to do this or alternatively how can I do this in other way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your GUI is not built using GUIDE you can set / modify the uitable properties like this (directly from http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/uitable.html):

```
f = figure('Position',[200 200 400 150]);
dat = rand(3); 
cnames = {'X-Data','Y-Data','Z-Data'};
rnames = {'First','Second','Third'};
t = uitable('Parent',f,'Data',dat,'ColumnName',cnames,... 
            'RowName',rnames,'Position',[20 20 360 100]);
```

Then you could modify the column names during execution by using:

```
cnames = {'Z-Data','Y-Data','X-Data'};
set(t,'ColumnName',cnames);
```

The only thing remaining is deciding which event will trigger this modification and writing the appropriate callback function. If you could give some details about the GUI it could be useful.

If you are building your GUI via GUIDE, I do not know if it is possible (I guess so but I generally prefer to avoid GUIDE so my knowledge is limited in this area).

**UPDATE:**

As an example, I wrote a small piece of code that shows this in action. In this case the event triggering the columns names change is a button but it could be anything, hope this helps.

```
% GUI
function so_uitable
% Layout
figure('units','normalized','position',[0.1 0.1 0.5 0.5],'tag','figure');
data=guihandles(gcf);
uitable('parent',data.figure,'units','normalized', ... 
    'Position', [0.1 0.1 0.35 0.8],'tag','table');
uicontrol('style','pushbutton','string','Change columns names', ... 
    'parent',data.figure,'units','normalized', ... 
    'Position',[0.55 0.8 0.35 0.1],'tag','button', ... 
    'callback',@button_callback);
data=guihandles(gcf); 
% Data
data.matrix=rand(3);
data.cnames={'X-Data','Y-Data','Z-Data'};
set(data.table,'data',data.matrix,'ColumnName',data.cnames);
guidata(gcf,data);
end
% Callback
function button_callback(obj,event)%#ok
data=guidata(gcbf);
n=length(data.cnames);
prompt=cell(n,1);
answer=inputdlg(prompt,'Change columns names',1,data.cnames);
if(~isempty(answer))
    data.cnames=answer;
    set(data.table,'ColumnName',data.cnames);
end
guidata(gcbf,data);
end
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I built the GUI using GUIDE. is there solution for that?

Comment: I think it would pretty much work in the same way, except that you have to use the callback functions and the objects handles provided by GUIDE. 

There is a simple video tutorial (http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2008/04/17/advanced-matlab-handles-and-other-inputs-to-guide-callbacks/) that explains how to use callbacks and objects handles with GUIDE. You can start from this video and try to modify your uitable properties from a callback and see how that goes. Unfortunately I have very few experience with GUIDE so I do not know how it will work out but I am sure it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

I made a table using GUIDE, and the following line of code was able to set the row names successfully:

```
set(data.table, 'ColumnName',data.cnames);
```